# Is Firebase Crashlytics can take my application data?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

> If i implement Firebase Crashlytics in my application; is Firebase
> have access my application data? i am working an application which fast priority is data secure.
>
> Is it wise to implement Firebase Crashlytics in my app, if not what should i do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Crashlytics doesnt obtain your data instead it detects and listens for any crashes in your app.

Most of the major security app do use Firebase for a number of different functionality because of its user-friendly and easier to access resources.
Make

Comment: Please do select the above ans as accepted so that others may know tat the answer solved your problem! Also, when u use any other services of Firebase, it doesnt access to your data as u create your project container over it with your cred

Comment: Make sure to not provide your project id, firebase SHA keys or anyother private data of Firebase to anyone. Note: Not even post it here as in your question in future

Comment: `Firebase Crashlytics doesnt obtain your data instead it detects and listens for any crashes in your app.` source ? any official documentation for saying this ?